# Entropy always increases. Then why did elementary particles come together to form an atom?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, entropy, big-bang, elementary-particles

It is generally said that entropy always increases. But after the Big Bang elementary particles came together to form an atom. Isn't that paradoxical ?

Answer (score 3):

No, the combination releases enough energy to heat the surroundings enough that the entropy increases.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Ross'answer.

Assuming the entropy of the quark plasma age, in order for quarks to bind into a proton , i.e. fall into a potential well, they must lose energy. This energy will be radiation of gluons and photons, and not a small number, as the strong coupling constant allows multiple gluons. In any case the [number of microstates increases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) so entropy increases. In order for protons to form into a hydrogen atom again energy has to be lost in the  form of a photon , and again the number of microstates increases. And so on for more complicated electromagnetic and strong bindings.

Comment: Thank you both for the help :)